# uses and proofs of the cardinality of the continuum

Tags: proof-explanation, cardinals, axiom-of-choice, axioms, homotopy-type-theory

after reading this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum

I wonder what good is it as a tool in mathematics if there is no proof. is it merely useful to prove that it is undecidable? wikipedia says no proof in ZFC but I wonder if there are other axiom systems that may be more or less strict where this problem may actually be decidable. for example, is there some weaker result that can be gained from homotopy type theory where there is some type with no distinction between different sets with the same cardinality? sorry if these are dumb questions. I still don't understand a lot of this but I am desperately trying to read as much as I can. I did not find this question asked exactly like this through search on this forum.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking about. The thing of which there is no proof (in ZFC) is *the continuum hypothesis* that is the hypothesis that there is no set of reals of cardinality strictly between that of the integers and that of the reals. It is useful to know that it is undecidable, as it keeps you from wasting your time trying to prove/disprove it. It's also fun, because it says you can prove other things taking CH as true, and different things taking CH as false, so you have twice as much mathematics to occupy your time and keep you off the streets.

Comment: the second part of my question asks if there is a weaker result using a different axiom system such as maybe for example ZF without choice.

Comment: I know nothing about homotopy type theory, but if ZFC can't decide CH, then certainly a weaker system can't decide it, either.

Comment: Your post says nothing about the axiom of choice. Frankly, it's not clear to me why this is bothering you too much. Do you think it's useless to prove that some fields admit a solution to $x^2-2=0$ and others don't? It's useless to prove that not all rings are fields, not all groups are abelian, and not all sets are singletons? Those are all examples of proving that something is unprovable.

Comment: You can have ZF without choice. That is the difference between ZF and ZFC. There are other axiom systems besides ZFC. I don't know all of them which why I asked if the problem is undecidable in all possible axiom systems.

Comment: There are axiom systems that decide the truth of CH, such as ZF+CH, or ZF+not-CH, or a bit more interestingly ZF + Freiling's axiom of symmetry, or even more interestingly ZF+(V=L).  But switching from ZF to HoTT doesn't change anything, since models of the two are interconstructible in a way that preserves the truth or falsity of CH.

Comment: You might be interested in [this expository article](https://iblech.gitlab.io/bb/multiverse.html) of mine, having an audience of interested programmers in mind. It discusses the continuum hypothesis in the context of the multiverse philosophy in set theory.

Comment: excellent responses both Mike and Ingo thank you.